# Z3 syntax highlighting for nano

Tags: syntax-highlighting, z3, nano

I am using the Z3 solver and am writing scripts for it such as the example given below:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (= (* x y) 10))
(assert (> x 0))
(assert (> y 0))
(minimize (+ x y))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I am primarily using nano in my terminal to edit these scripts, but I would like to have syntax highlighting when I do this. Is there a `z3.nanorc` file somewhere that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt one exists for nano. If you choose a lisp syntax highlighter, it should *mostly* do the job, however. Maybe start from this: https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight/blob/master/lisp.nanorc